# Lost installed ubuntu os after restart, Computer starts on try-without install or install ubuntu

Tags: boot, reboot, system

What the title says, happened to a friend. While trying to transfer some files to his usb stick, a notification popped up, which he couldn't close, so he restarted his machine. After restart, his was prompted with the try ubuntu, which is automatically selected or install ubuntu. I asked him what the notification said, to which he told me he didn't pay attention to, but it had the word **net**. Any ideas to what happened?

Edit: Problem solved, friend is stupid. The usb he used had Ubuntu installation files. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Tell you friend to remove the USB drive when booting;-)

Comment: Best not to shutdown unless last resort as that also can corrupt system and then require fsck. Remember the elephants: https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes Generally pressing and holding Ctrl+Alt and
then PrintScr, R, E, I, S, U, B (Raising Elephants Is So Utterly Boring)

Comment: @Pilot6 You are a god lol. He brought it to me without the usb and everything worked fine. That's when it hit me that this happened. The usb he tried to use to copy his files was also an Ubuntu installation usb.

Comment: @oldfred R, E, I is disabled for a long time. Only SUB is left.

Comment: I am getting too old to remember a new mnemonic. :)

Comment: @Pilot6 do you have a source for "is disabled...." ?

Comment: @guntbert You can do it yourself. Don't worry about "copyright"

Answer (score 1):

This looks very much like the installation started afresh after every reboot.

The most common cause for this is that the installation media (USB stick,...) is still plugged in.